# How to see pull up all relevant info from a table given a list of values SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently I have a list of manufacturing numbers in a table called "Mfr_Numbers_Table".
I also have a master table called Billings

I would like to generate a query where I see all line items that matches with what is on Mfr_Numbers_Tables from the Billings Table.

How do I do this? I can just write 50 queries with a where clause being the Mfr_numbers, but that would take too long.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need put the tables in a relation in your query.
This is done by a join on the tables on a field which is in both of them.

For example if this field is named `MfrNumber`:

```
Select Billings.*, Mfr_Numbers_Table.*
From Mfr_Numbers_Table Inner Join Billings
On Mfr_Numbers_Table.MfrNumber = Billings.MfrNumber
```

Usually you don't select all fields from all joined tables, but select what you really need.

Also you can still filter (`Where`) and/or order (`Order By`) the result.

The name of the joined field isn't relevant, but its datatype and for sure the content.

For more please read this article: [Join tables and queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3F5838BD-24A0-4832-9BC1-07061A1478F6)